# Inclusion-Exclusion Principle: an easy application

Tags: combinatorics, computational-complexity, inclusion-exclusion

[Here](http://62.182.86.140/main/71000/ce490c8f1d68a11dd52056856dbc3670/Oded%20Goldreich%20-%20Computational%20complexity_%20A%20conceptual%20perspective-Cambridge%20University%20Press%20%282008%29.pdf) is an interesting book. If the download doesn't start copy and paste that link to your browser.
Indeed, I'm unable to apply the **Inclusion-Exclusion principle** to an instance of it.
How have we obtained the *lower bound* here and how would it continue with more terms ?

$$\sum_{y\in R(x)} \text{Pr}_{h\in H^{m_x}_l}[h(y)=0^{m_x}]-\sum_{y_1<y_2\in R(x)} \text{Pr}_{h\in H^{m_x}_l}[h(y_1)=h(y_2)=0^{m_x}]$$.

My confusion lies in the fact that I would thing that we should **extract** from first term yet this and so that the result would look like this

$$\sum_{y\in R(x)} \text{Pr}_{h\in H^{m_x}_l}[h(y)=0^{m_x}]-\sum_{y_1<y_2\in R(x)} \text{Pr}_{h\in H^{m_x}_l}[h(y_1)=h(y_2)=0^{m_x}]-\color{red}{\sum_{y_1<y_2\in R(x)} \text{Pr}_{h\in H^{m_x}_l}[h(y_1)=h(y_2)=1^{m_x}]}$$

[image]

Comment: That text starts with a lot of things undefined.

Comment: And why do you say it is easy? It never says so in the text, so what makes you say that?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Right. I've added a link to the entire book and for your second objection I would just guess it is something very elemental.

Comment: It's generally unwise to use words like "easy" to describe a question here. A person, looking at your title alone, will expect a beginning exercise in Inclusion-Exclusion, not a complex multi-page question that requires a **lot** of context, which strays far from a basic Inclusion/Exclusion example.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I've updated my Q. Is it better now ?

Comment: The problem starts with the title. That is the reason people read your question, and if you mislead there. you are wasting people's time.

Comment: I appreciate you including the reference to the book you obtained the question from @user122424. It is good to make your questions as self-contained as possible. However, it is best to provide the minimal explanation necessary that illustrates your question. Unless I misunderstood what you were asking in my answer, it seems that your question was fundamentally only about the inclusion-exclusion principle. As such, it wasn't necessary to include all the background from Goldreich's book. You could have replaced the unexplained symbols in your question with generic placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that each term in the summation of the inclusion-exclusion principle "extracts" (by which I assume you meant *subtracts*) from the previous term, but when you distribute the negations in the sum certain terms end up being positive! Let's say I have some events $E_1, E_2,...,E_k$, and I wish to lower bound $\Pr(\bigcup^k_{i=1}E_i)$. The Inclusion-Exclusion principle tells us:

$$\Pr(\bigcup^k_{i=1}E_i) = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 \leq k}\Pr(E_{i_1}) \color{red}{-} \left( \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 \leq k}\Pr(E_{i_1} \cap E_{i_2}) - \color{blue}{\left( ... \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < ... <i_{l} \leq k}\Pr(\bigcap^{l}_{j=1} E_{i_j}) - \left(...\right) ...\right)} \right)$$

for $l \in [k]$. However, if my goal is simply to lower bound $\Pr(\bigcup^k_{i=1}E_i)$, then I can stop at the second term of this summation, since any subsequent terms in the blue part of the summation above would only add to the total sum once you distribute the red minus sign.

Comment: I do not follow everything from your answer. What do you mean by this $l\in[k]$ and how is related this $$\sum_{y\in R(x)} \text{Pr}_{h\in H^{m_x}_l}[h(y)=0^{m_x}]-\sum_{y_1<y_2\in R(x)} \text{Pr}_{h\in H^{m_x}_l}[h(y_1)=h(y_2)=0^{m_x}]-\color{red}{\sum_{y_1<y_2\in R(x)} \text{Pr}_{h\in H^{m_x}_l}[h(y_1)=h(y_2)=1^{m_x}]}$$
 with this

Comment: $$\Pr(\bigcup^k_{i=1}E_i) = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 \leq k}\Pr(E_{i_1}) \color{blue}{\color{green}{-} \left( \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 \leq k}\Pr(E_{i_1} \cap E_{i_2}) \right)}$$

Comment: Right. It is also worth mentioning that instead of first term $$\sum_{1 \leq i_1 \leq k}\Pr(E_{i_1})$$ I insert the truncated one: $$\sum_{1 \leq i_1 \leq k}\Pr(h(y_1)=0^{m_x}).$$ Is that correct ?